# Creating a directory on external sd card that will have a text file written to it

Tags: android

I am trying to create a folder on my `external SDcard` that will contain a text file that I can pull off my phone from my PC and read it.

I have pieced together a `snippet` that I believe should work, but I cannot find the folder that is supposedly being created.

```java
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/iptestdata/");
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
   }
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss'.txt'").format(new Date());
final File file = new File(dir, fileName);
```

As I am stepping though the `debugger` in `Android Studio`, I see the path being created and stored in `dir` is `/storage/emulated/0/iptestdata`, and I see the `file name` appearing in the format that I requested, but I cannot find the file via `File Explorer` in Windows.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you create File and store into storage Directory you want to call `mkdirs()`

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + " /dir - name /");
dir.mkdir();
File file = new File(dir, "File-Name.txt");
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
String data = "This is the content of my file";
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();
```

Please check the Directory is created or not  the following method

```
  public static boolean canWriteOnExternalStorage() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Log.v("Activity", "Yes, can write to external storage.");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Add Permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I've updated the permission in androidmanifest.xml, but I'm still not seeing where this code is saving to my external sd card.  The dir path is still going to /storage/emulated/0/iptestdata.  Is there another method I can use to create the folder on my external sd card?